# Orthogonal axes of rotation of angle $\pi$ implies AB=BA

Tags: real-analysis, matrices

Let A and B be in SO(3) each with angle of rotation $\pi$.

Prove that AB=BA if and only if the axes of rotation are the same (or the negative of each other) or perpendicular to each other.

I can prove the implication assuming AB=BA by picking a point S on A's axis of rotation and noting that A(S)=S so B(S)=BA(S)=AB(S) so S must be on B's axis of rotation or the axes must be perpendicular.

The implication from axis(A)=axis(B) is obvious, but I'm not sure how to prove that AB=BA assuming the axes are perpendicular. Pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are a math major, the quick way to see this is to apply the theorem that two normal matrices commute if and only if they can be simultaneously unitarily diagonalisable (over $\mathbb C$).

Answer (score 1):

A rotation by angle $\pi$ around a line $\ell$
is a reflection through line $\ell$.

You could choose an ordered list of three points $(P,Q,R)$
that are not coplanar with the origin, transform $(P,Q,R)$ by $AB$
once to obtain $(P_1,Q_1,R_1)$,
and transform $(P,Q,R)$ by $BA$ to obtain $(P_2,Q_2,R_2)$.
Compare the two resulting lists of points. What do they tell you about
$AB$ and $BA$?

If the two axes of rotation are not parallel (i.e. the same axis or
opposite), you can put $P$ and $Q$ on the two axes and put $R$
on the line perpendicular to both axes.
That should make things easier.
(I think it also makes a relatively easy proof of the "only if" part too.)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: A linear transformation $T$ on $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ is a rotation by $\pi$ about some line $\ell$ if and only if

- $\ell$ is a $1$-eigenspace of $T$, and
- the plane $\ell^{\perp}$ orthogonal to $\ell$ is a $(-1)$-eigenspace of $T$.