# Find rigid body transform $T_b$, given transforms $T_a, T_c$, where $T_c = T_b^{-1}T_aT_b$ for $T_b$. i.e. find change of basis.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, rotations, kinematics, rigid-transformation

Let $\mathbf{T}_a, \mathbf{T}_b, \mathbf{T}_c \in SE(3)$ be rigid body transforms, and;

$$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{T}_c = \mathbf{T}_b^{-1}\mathbf{T}_a\mathbf{T}_b. 
\label{eq_basis}
\end{equation}
$$

We wish to find $\mathbf{T}_b$ given $\mathbf{T}_a, \mathbf{T}_c$.

I think this is equivalent to finding a change of basis between $\mathbf{T}_a$ and $\mathbf{T}_c$. My approach so far has been to decompose the problem into rotational and translational constraints as follows.

Let $\mathbf{R}_a \in SO(3)$ be the rotational component of $\mathbf{T}_a$, and $\mathbf{t}_a$ be the translational component. Then we have:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R}_c & \mathbf{t}_c\\ \mathbf{0} & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R}^{\top}_b & -\mathbf{R}^{\top}_b\mathbf{t}_b\\ \mathbf{0} & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R}_a & \mathbf{t}_a\\ \mathbf{0} & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R}_b & \mathbf{t}_b\\ \mathbf{0} & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Expanding this equation and collecting terms gives the following set of matrix equations;

$$
(1)\ \ \ \mathbf{R}_c = \mathbf{R}^{\top}_b\mathbf{R}_a\mathbf{R}_b\\
(2)\ \ \ \mathbf{t}_c = \mathbf{R}^{\top}_b\mathbf{R}_a\mathbf{t}_b + \mathbf{R}^{\top}_b\mathbf{t}_a - \mathbf{R}^{\top}_b\mathbf{t}_b
$$

In general, (1) has infinitely many solutions which form a circle. We can find them by the following;

Let $\mathbf{c}$ be the rotation axis of $\mathbf{R}_c$, i.e. $\mathbf{R}_c\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{c}$. Then;

$$
\mathbf{R}_c\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{R}^{\top}_b\mathbf{R}_a\mathbf{R}_b\mathbf{c} \\
\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{R}^{\top}_b\mathbf{R}_a\mathbf{R}_b\mathbf{c} \\
\mathbf{R}_b\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{R}_a\mathbf{R}_b\mathbf{c}
$$

This means $\mathbf{R}_b\mathbf{c}$ is parallel to the rotation axis of $\mathbf{R}_a$. Hence $\mathbf{R}_b$ can be taken as any rotation taking $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{c}$, i.e. a rotation of the rotation axes.

As stated, there are infinitely many such rotations. We may choose $\mathbf{R}_b$ to be for example the rotation in the plane given by $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{c}$ by the angle $acos(\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c}}{|\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{c}|})$. There are a few degenerate cases, for example if $\mathbf{R}_c = \mathbf{I}$ or $\mathbf{R}_a = \mathbf{I}$, or if $\mathbf{R}_c = \mathbf{R}_a$. I dealt with those [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3677405/788920).

This takes care of (1).

Substituting our choice for $\mathbf{R}_b$ into (2), and solving for $\mathbf{t}_b$ we find;

$$
\left(\mathbf{R}_a - \mathbf{I}_{3\times3}\right)\mathbf{t}_b = \mathbf{R}_b\mathbf{t}_c - \mathbf{t}_a
$$

Where $\mathbf{I}_{3\times3}$ is the 3x3 identity matrix. The term $\mathbf{R}_a - \mathbf{I}_{3\times3}$ gives a singular matrix since $\mathbf{R}_a$ has only 1 as its eigenvalue. The resulting system therefore has zero or infinitely many solutions for any choice of $\mathbf{R}_b$.

When does this system have solutions at all? What are the additional constraints? Is there a neater way of approaching this problem? What additional constraints are necessary to give a unique solution?